# Display error in bootstrap select

Tags: laravel, select

In a Laravel project, i have the following display error:

[image]

The code:

```php
    <!-- Status Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    {!! Form::label('status_id', __('project.status')) !!}
    {!! Form::select('status_id', $templateProjectStatus, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

There is no special styling for it.

How i can improve the styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0):

The Form Helper is not part of the laravel framework, as using bootstrap,

you can add needed class for styling it like this :

are you correctly include the bootstrap files ? Because it seems that no class are applied on your form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: I do not find any error in bootstrap file including